# After rotating screen, always first timer beginning a count

Tags: android, listview, timer

Half month i trying fix this problem, its my second solution and i get old error.
My goal is to write a listView with timer in every row with Start and Stop buttons, after rotating screen all timers should work correctly, but how in pre-solution after rotation screen, first position in listview get time last/lower position. 
As for link with these two solution i see just logic of getView() method, and i'm on 100% sure that is the main problem.

Can anybody help me with this, i am at an impasse. Problematic piace of code:

```
 if(isItStart.get(position)){
            holder.stop.setEnabled(true);
            holder.start.setEnabled(false);
            handler.postDelayed(updateTimeThread,0);
        }
```

Here is full class.

```
 ListView listView;
MyAdapter adapter;
Handler handler;
SQLiteDatabase db;
List<Tracker> trackerList;
Tracker tracker;
List<Boolean> isItStart,historyIsItStart;
List<Long> startTime,historyStartTime;
List<Long> lastPauseList,historyLastPauseList;
List<Long> updateTimeList, historyUpdateTimeList;
List<Long> daysList,historyDayList;
List<Long> hoursList,historyHoursList;
List<Long> minutesList,historyMinutes;
List<Long> secondsList,historySecondsList;
int trackerCount;


static final String LOG_TAG = "myTag";


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    handler = new Handler();
    db = RemindMe.db;
    trackerList = Tracker.getListAll(db);
    trackerCount=trackerList.size();
    initLists();
    for (int i = 0; i < trackerCount; i++) {
        startTime.add(0L);
        lastPauseList.add(0L);
        updateTimeList.add(0L);
        daysList.add(0L);
        hoursList.add(0L);
        minutesList.add(0L);
        secondsList.add(0L);
        isItStart.add(false);

            historyStartTime.add(startTime.get(i));
            historyLastPauseList.add(lastPauseList.get(i));
            historyUpdateTimeList.add(updateTimeList.get(i));
            historyDayList.add(daysList.get(i));
            historyHoursList.add(hoursList.get(i));
            historyMinutes.add(minutesList.get(i));
            historySecondsList.add(secondsList.get(i));
            historyIsItStart.add(isItStart.get(i));
    }

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    String[] from = {Tracker.COL_NAME,Tracker.COL_ELAPSED_TIME,Tracker.COL_ELAPSED_TIME,Tracker.COL_ELAPSED_TIME,Tracker.COL_ELAPSED_TIME};
    int[] to = {R.id.tvName,R.id.tvDays,R.id.tvHours,R.id.tvMinutes,R.id.tvSeconds};
    adapter = new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,Tracker.getAll(db),from,to,0);
    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            long day,hour,min,sec;
            long time = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
            switch(view.getId()){
                case R.id.tvDays:
                    TextView days = (TextView)view;
                    days.setText("days");
                    return true;
                case R.id.tvHours:
                    TextView hours = (TextView)view;
                    hours.setText("hours");
                    return true;
                case R.id.tvMinutes:
                    TextView minutes = (TextView)view;

                    minutes.setText("min");
                    return true;
                case R.id.tvSeconds:
                    TextView seconds = (TextView)view;
                    if(time!=0){
                        sec = time/1000;
                        seconds.setText(String.valueOf(sec));
                    }else{
                        seconds.setText("null");
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,this).forceLoad();

}
void initLists(){
    startTime = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    lastPauseList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    updateTimeList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    daysList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    hoursList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    minutesList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    secondsList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    isItStart = new ArrayList<Boolean>(trackerCount);


    historySecondsList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    historyMinutes = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    historyHoursList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    historyDayList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    historyUpdateTimeList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    historyLastPauseList = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    historyStartTime = new ArrayList<Long>(trackerCount);
    historyIsItStart = new ArrayList<Boolean>(trackerCount);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddTrack.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new TrackerLoader(this,db);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

}
static class TrackerLoader extends android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader{
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    TrackerLoader(Context context,SQLiteDatabase db){
        super(context);
        this.db=db;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
       return Tracker.getAll(db);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSavedInstanceState---------------------------------------------------------------!");

    for (int i = 0; i <trackerCount ; i++) {
        historyStartTime.set(i,startTime.get(i));
        historyLastPauseList.set(i, lastPauseList.get(i));
        historyUpdateTimeList.set(i,updateTimeList.get(i));
        historyDayList.set(i, daysList.get(i));
        historyHoursList.set(i,hoursList.get(i));
        historyMinutes.set(i, minutesList.get(i));
        historySecondsList.set(i,secondsList.get(i));
        historyIsItStart.set(i, isItStart.get(i));

        outState.putSerializable("startTime " + i, historyStartTime.get(i));
        outState.putSerializable("lastPause " + i, historyLastPauseList.get(i));
        outState.putSerializable("updateTime " + i, historyUpdateTimeList.get(i));
        outState.putSerializable("dayList " + i, historyDayList.get(i));
        outState.putSerializable("hoursList " + i, historyHoursList.get(i));
        outState.putSerializable("minutesList " + i, historyMinutes.get(i));
        outState.putSerializable("secondsList " + i, historySecondsList.get(i));
        outState.putSerializable("isItStart " + i, historyIsItStart.get(i));

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startTime " + getTime((Long) outState.getSerializable("startTime " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "lastPause " + getTime((Long) outState.getSerializable("lastPause " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "updateTime " + getTime((Long) outState.getSerializable("updateTime " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "dayList " + getTime((Long) outState.getSerializable("dayList " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "hoursList " + getTime((Long) outState.getSerializable("hoursList " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "minutesList " + getTime((Long) outState.getSerializable("minutesList " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "secondsList " +  outState.getSerializable("secondsList " + i));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "isItStart " + outState.getSerializable("isItStart " + i));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "position " + i);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"-----------------------------------!");
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"END onSavedInstanceState-------------------------------------------------------------!");
    for (int i = 0; i < trackerCount; i++) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"secondsList "+i+ " "+secondsList.get(i));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState-------------------------------------------------------!");

    for (int i = 0; i <trackerCount ; i++) {
        historyStartTime.set(i,(Long)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("startTime "+i));
        historyLastPauseList.set(i,(Long)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("lastPause "+i));
        historyUpdateTimeList.set(i,(Long)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("updateTime "+i));
        historyDayList.set(i,(Long)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("dayList "+i));
        historyHoursList.set(i,(Long)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("hoursList "+i));
        historyMinutes.set(i,(Long)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("minutesList "+i));
        historySecondsList.set(i,(Long)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("secondsList "+i));
        historyIsItStart.set(i,(Boolean)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("isItStart "+i));

        startTime.set(i,historyStartTime.get(i));
        lastPauseList.set(i,historyLastPauseList.get(i));
        updateTimeList.set(i,historyUpdateTimeList.get(i));
        daysList.set(i,historyDayList.get(i));
        hoursList.set(i,historyHoursList.get(i));
        minutesList.set(i,historyMinutes.get(i));
        secondsList.set(i,historySecondsList.get(i));
        isItStart.set(i, historyIsItStart.get(i));


        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startTime " + getTime((Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("startTime " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"lastPause " + getTime((Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("lastPause " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"updateTime " + getTime((Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("updateTime " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"dayList " + getTime((Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("dayList " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"hoursList " + getTime((Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("hoursList " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"minutesList " + getTime((Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("minutesList " + i)));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "secondsList " + savedInstanceState.getSerializable("secondsList " + i));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"isItStart "+savedInstanceState.getSerializable("isItStart " + i));
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"position "+i);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"----------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"END onRestoreIntstanceState-------------------------------------------------------------!");
}

private class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{
    Context context;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    MyAdapter(Context context,int resourceID,Cursor cursor,String[] from,int[]to,int flags){
        super(context, resourceID, cursor, from, to, flags);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        tracker = trackerList.get(position);
        if(row==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
            holder.name= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.days = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvDays);
            holder.hours = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvHours);
            holder.minutes = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvMinutes);
            holder.seconds = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvSeconds);
            holder.start = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
            holder.stop = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btStop);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        holder.start.setEnabled(true);
        holder.stop.setEnabled(false);
        holder.name.setText(tracker.getName());
                     final Runnable updateTimeThread = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    updateTimeList.set(position, (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime.get(position)) + lastPauseList.get(position));
                    secondsList.set(position, updateTimeList.get(position) / 1000);
                    minutesList.set(position, secondsList.get(position) / 60);
                    hoursList.set(position, minutesList.get(position) / 60);

                    secondsList.set(position, (secondsList.get(position) % 60));
                    minutesList.set(position, (minutesList.get(position) % 60));
                    hoursList.set(position, (hoursList.get(position) % 24));

                    holder.days.setText(String.format("%04d", daysList.get(position)));
                    holder.hours.setText(String.format("%02d", hoursList.get(position)));
                    holder.minutes.setText(String.format("%02d", minutesList.get(position)));
                    holder.seconds.setText(String.format("%02d", secondsList.get(position)));
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
            }
        };
        if(isItStart.get(position)){
            holder.stop.setEnabled(true);
            holder.start.setEnabled(false);
            handler.postDelayed(updateTimeThread,0);
        }
        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.btStart:
                        startTime.set(position,System.currentTimeMillis());
                        handler.post(updateTimeThread);
                        holder.start.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.stop.setEnabled(true);
                        isItStart.set(position,true);
                        break;
                    case R.id.btStop:
                        lastPauseList.set(position, updateTimeList.get(position));
                        handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeThread);
                        holder.stop.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.start.setEnabled(true);
                        isItStart.set(position,false);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        holder.start.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        holder.stop.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        return row;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView name,days,hours,minutes,seconds;
        Button start,stop;
    }

}
String getTime(long time){
    int hours = (int)(time/3600000);
    int minutes = (int)(time -hours*3600000)/60000;
    int seconds = (int)(time-hours*3600000-minutes*60000)/1000;
    String hour = (hours<9?"0"+hours:hours).toString();
    String min = (minutes<9?"0"+minutes:minutes).toString();
    String sec = (seconds<9?"0"+seconds:seconds).toString();
    return ""+hour+":"+min+":"+sec;
}
```

}

Comment: if you think it is due to rotation, you can add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" in manifest.xml and remove your saveinstanceState

Comment: @ajeet 
i know, but i must implement rotation screen

Comment: The android:configChanges prevents runtime restart in screen rotation. So you don't have to take care externally in saveInstanceState.

Comment: @Ajeet
i add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" it seems working, but i dont know properly this or not. Because it meens activity is not reacreated as should, and i can delete onSaved and onRestore methods

Comment: Glad it helped :) and Yes you can delete onRestore and onSaved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest.xml and delete your onRestore and onSaved.

Answer (score 0):

When you rotating the screen the application refresh the activity i had the same kind of problem so i just locked the screen for one way in the android mainifest by
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"

found this great answer by:Xion

"you could distinguish the cases of your activity being created for the first time and being restored from savedInstanceState. This is done by overriding onSaveInstanceState and checking the parameter of onCreate.

You could lock the activity in one orientation by adding android:screenOrientation="portrait" (or "landscape") to  in your manifest.

You could tell the system that you meant to handle screen changes for yourself by specifying android:configChanges="orientation" in the  tag. This way the activity will not be recreated, but will receive a callback instead (which you can ignore as it's not useful for you)."

Comment: its truly a great solution, i add android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" it seems working, but i dont know properly this or not. Because it meens activity is not reacreated as should, and i can delete onSaved and onRestore methods

Comment: didnt get you can you explain?"but i dont know properly this or not"

Comment: i cant objective explain this, but today in searching of solution this problem i reviewd a lot of open source projects on github and they all implement onSaved and onRestore methods. as example toggl tracker

Comment: like that : protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: if it helped you hope you can mark this as an answer :)